# php poll program using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a poll program and am wondering, so far all of the sample I've seen makes use of insert then counting the total votes for each answers. I find it redundant to have a table with a field of answers and a lot of yes, no and maybe

So I am thinking, is it efficient for me to use update instead of insert, for example, if a user vote yes, the yes field will increment? Will it introduce problems with accuracy if users simultaneously vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database uses transactions, the update will be atomic. There's no problem with accuracy.

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn=MyColumn+1 WHERE MyVoteID=123
```

Comment: Well, MtSQL no longer uses MyISAM by default. And ... it was directly answering his question if there would be a problem with "accuracy" if he used an update for a "vote count", which obviously there won't be. The update *is* atomic in that it can't be interleaved with another one.

Comment: What I wanted to emphasize is that transactions are not a solution to all concurrency problems. Lost updates, phantom reads, non repeatable reads, etc. *can* happen with transactions or not.

Comment: I agree that they are not the solution to all problems; absolutely. However, in this case, the update is a fine solution if he doesn't care *who* cast the vote (which is what his question implies)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a answer table, after you will have a relationship with user and answer.
You could get stats in adding some information (datetime, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

> I find it redundant to have a table with a field of answers and a lot of yes, no and maybe

you can add some useful info too, i.e. time of the vote, ip address, cookie and such

> Will it introduce problems

No